# Calling nonexistent functions of None

Tags: python

If I name an exception as a variable, what properties are held by that variable? For example,

```
try:
    None.nonexistent_function()
    #return an AttributeError.
except Exception as ex:
    self.assertEqual(__, ex.__class__.__name__)
```

In this instance, what is necessary to make the assertion True? How can the Name and Class of the Exception be determined?

*This question is part of Python Koans, a recent port of Ruby Koans.*

Comment: The premise is silly. You should catch specific exceptions, not all exceptions and then comparing the names.

Comment: Agree that the premise is a bit silly - but the objective here is to learn how aspects of Python work using prewritten 'problems', and not to write efficient code.

Comment: It's not a matter of efficiency. It's a matter of learning good habits. Teaching materials should **NEVER** do stuff like this. Also, `unittest` has `assertRaises` to wrap `try...except E`.

Comment: All that should be taught is that `ex` is -- ***IS*** -- the object that was thrown by `raise`. The `except Exception` stuff is just a class filter.

Comment: The code example looks weird in isolation, but this is because it is part of an interactive tutorial that teaches by making unit tests pass, mostly by replacing __ variables with values. There's an online version: http://koans.pyc.io/about_asserts that you can examine to quickly see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Try it at the REPL:

```
>>> try: None.foo()
... except Exception as ex: pass
...
>>> # ex is still in scope, so we can play around with it and find out for ourselves:
... ex.__class__.__name__
'AttributeError'
>>>
```

Comment: Good suggestion on the pass. Allows more testing to be done on #ex. The nature of __class__ and __name__ as attributes of #ex are still unclear.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the nature of" attributes? (My first wise-ass reaction is along the lines of "they have the attribute nature, of course.")

Comment: All objects have a __class__ method thats you what type or class it is an instance of. For example 'print "I am a string".__class__' will return <type 'str'>. This tells you that "I am a string" is an instance of the str type. All classes and types also have a __name__ argument which tells you the name as a string. So 'print "I am a string".__class__.__name__' will give you 'str'.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... using Python's command line, I get:

```
>>> try:
...     None.nonexistent_function()
...     #return an AttributeError.
... except Exception as ex:
...     print ex.__class__.__name__
... 
AttributeError
>>>
```

So let's try:

```
>>> try:
...     None.nonexistent_function()
...     #return an AttributeError.
... except Exception as ex:
...     print 'AttributeError' == ex.__class__.__name__
... 
True
```

I don't have whatever your `self` object is handy, so you'll have to test the rest. Does that work for you?

Comment: Good call on printing an equality rather than making an assertion pass. What would your next step be to determine the values for __class__ and __name__? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't have any idea what you think "the values for `__class__` and `__name__`" means. The exception is an object. `__class__` is an attribute of that object: specifically, a reference to another object that represents the exception's class. `__name__` is an attribute of that object, which is a string representation of the name.